# LIMIT Display of a different table field

Tags: mysql, sql

Below are my tables:

```
1. tbluser
UserNumber - PK
Name    
MemberType - Number
StationNumber - FK (connected to StationNo of tblStation)

2.tblStation
StationNo - PK
StationName

3.tblUserLogs
LogID - PK
UserID - FK (connected from UserNumber of tblusers)
LastLog
```

And all I want to do is to display Name (tblusers), StationName(tblStation) and LastLog(tblUserLogs) where MemberType is not equal to 1.

Here's my try...

```
SELECT tblusers.FirstName, tblstation.StationName, tblUserLogs.LastLog
FROM (tblstation INNER JOIN tblusers ON tblstation.StationNo = tblusers.StationNumber) 
     INNER JOIN tblUserLogs ON tblusers.UserNumber = tblUserLogs.UserID
WHERE (((tblusers.MemberType)<>1))
```

However, I get repeating records of my users. It displays ALL the LastLog data instead of showing the latest.

How should I do it?

Comment: Where's the code/structure for `tblusers`? EDIT: I assume it's the first one, just using the wrong name...

Comment: @jerdiggity I think "1. tblStation" is typo. "1. tblUser" is correct one.

Comment: Sorry, typo. Edited now :)

Comment: No worries... Also, most the answers below used `FirstName` even though the column name appears to be `Name` instead... I changed mine to reflect what you wrote but could you clarify which is correct?

Comment: @jerdiggity Its FirstName and LastName in my db and changed it to Name here on my question

Comment: Gotcha. Updated below, but is the table name `tblusers` or `tbluser`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT tblusers.FirstName, tblstation.StationName, MAX(tblUserLogs.LastLog)
FROM (tblusers LEFT JOIN tblstation ON tblstation.StationNo = tblusers.StationNumber)
     LEFT JOIN tblUserLogs ON tblusers.UserNumber = tblUserLogs.UserID
WHERE tblusers.MemberType != 1
```

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) near tblstation INNER JOIN tblusers ON tblstation.StationNo = tblusers.StationNumber

Comment: @Sarah I am not using the `INNER JOIN`  check my query.

Comment: still on the left join. :(

Comment: @Sarah Now you can give the +1